# Porque este Tooltip no se muestra?

Tags: html, css, tooltip

Tengo el siguiente documento HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF=8">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tooltip.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <title>Tooltip</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Tooltip</h2>
    <div class="menu">
    <div class="boton-seleccion">Posiciona el mouse aqui</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

la intención era crear un Tooltip que apareciera 2 segundos después de colocar el cursor sobre un botón ya que era un ejercicio de una clase, seguí todo el ejemplo escribí el código tal cual pero no logro que salga la ventanita del Tooltip. Ya lo he revisado con el ejemplo mil veces y esta escrito tal cual. Quizás haya que agregar algo al documento HTML, alguien que me pueda dar una idea de donde esta el error (recién estoy empezando en este mundillo).

Aquí el archivo CSS

```
body{
    margin: 10px 10px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: condensed;
}

.menu{
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.boton-seleccion{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #999999;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid #FFCC00;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu:hover .boton-seleccion{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #FFCC00;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
}

.menu .tooltiptext{
    width: auto;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 110%;
    left: 50%;
    color: #666666;
    border-color: #FFFF99;
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #999999;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.menu:hover:active .tooltiptext{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1; 
    transition: 500ms;
    border: 30px dashed black;

}
```

Comment: donde tienes el elemento `.tooltiptext`? no lo veo en el html

Comment: aca en el pdf me dice que la clase tooltiptext esta relacionada con menu y con eso deberia ser suficiente, por eso digo quizas habia que agregar algo al html y aca no dice

Comment: Perdona pero aquí no somos adivinos... para poder ayudarte debes incluir en la pregunta todo lo relacionado con ella. Sino, así es muy complicado. Te sugiero revisar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask